# Why do I need to define varibales in this example while sorting multiple lists at once in Python(3)?

Tags: python-3.x

Simple problem.
I've got these lists:

```
alpha = [5,10,1,2]
beta = [1,5,2]
gamma = [5,2,87,100,1]
```

I thought I could sort them all with:

```
map(lambda x: list.sort(x),[alpha,beta,gamma])
```

Which doesn't work.
What is working though is:

```
a,b,c = map(lambda x: list.sort(x),[alpha,beta,gamma])
```

Can someone explain why I need to define a,b and c for this code to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `map()` is *lazy* (since Python 3). It returns a generator-like object that is only evaluated when its contents are asked for, for instance because you want to assign its individual elements to variables.

E.g., this also forces it to evaluate:

```
>>> list(map(lambda x: list.sort(x),[alpha,beta,gamma]))
```

But using map is a bit archaic, list comprehensions and generator comprehensions exist and are almost always more idiomatic. Also, `list.sort(x)` is a bit of an odd way to write `x.sort()` that may or may not work, avoid it.

```
[x.sort() for x in [alpha, beta, gamma]]
```

works as you expected.

But if you aren't interested in the result, building a list isn't relevant. What you really want is a simple *for loop*:

```
for x in [alpha, beta, gamma]:
    x.sort()
```

Which is perfectly Pythonic, except that I maybe like this one even better in this fixed, simple case:

```
alpha.sort()
beta.sort()
gamma.sort()
```

can't get more explicit than that.

Answer (score 0):

Its is because `list.sort()` returns `None`. It sorts the list in place

If you want to sort them lists and return it do this:

> a,b,c = (sorted(l) for l in [alpha, beta, gamma])

```
In [10]: alpha.sort()

In [11]: sorted(alpha)
Out[11]: [1, 2, 5, 10]
```

Comment: No, that it returns None doesn't explain why it only works if you do something with the result.